# How to use getElementByID in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this test which first asks email and password for Facebook with inputbox. Then it should go to (www.facebook.com) on Internet Explorer and login with your email and password, but it gives me error (Run-time error '424' Object required). I don't know what is wrong with this code so if you could help I would be glad.

```
Sub FB_Login()

Dim Site As Object
Set Site = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
Dim FB_ID As String
Dim FB_PW As String
Dim URL As String

FB_ID = InputBox("Give me email for FB")
FB_PW = InputBox("Give me password for FB")
URL = "Facebook.com"

Site.navigate URL
While Site.busy
    Wend

Site.document.getElementById("email").Value = FB_ID 'Gives error
Site.document.getElementById("pass").Value = FB_PW  'Run-time error '424'
Site.document.getElementById("loginbutton").Click   'Object required

While Site.busy
    Wend
Site.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Thank you all for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help?

```
Option Explicit

Sub FB_Login()

    Dim Site As Object
    Set Site = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    Dim FB_ID As String
    Dim FB_PW As String
    Dim URL As String

    FB_ID = InputBox("Give me email for FB")
    FB_PW = InputBox("Give me password for FB")
    URL = "Facebook.com"

    Site.navigate URL
    While Site.busy
    Wend

    Dim oHTMLDoc As Object
    Set oHTMLDoc = Site.document

    oHTMLDoc.getElementById("email").Value = FB_ID    'Gives error
    oHTMLDoc.getElementById("pass").Value = FB_PW  'Run-time error '424'
    oHTMLDoc.getElementById("loginbutton").Click   'Object required

    While Site.busy
    Wend
    Site.Visible = True

End Sub
```